# Return value mysql if not exist for one condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to return the value even if value not exist. For example the user with id = 245 has value only for year 2017, but the idea is to return value 0 for year 2016 and value = 0 for year = 2018 if no data in database.

```
SELECT member_id, year,
   SUM(amount_nitrogen) as amount_nitrogen,   
   SUM(amount_potassium) as amount_potassium,
   SUM(amount_phosphorus) as amount_phosphorus,
   SUM(amount_sodium_oxide) as amount_sodium_oxide
   FROM ct 
WHERE year >= 2016 and year <= 2018
GROUP BY  member_id, year
```

If the user has data for all 3 years : 2018,2017,2016 it's good, but if the user has only for one year, I get data only for this year. The scope is to get data for others 2 years and this data shoul be 0

Comment: Instead of writing "year >= 2016 and year <= 2018", use "year between 2016 and 2018", you could also try using a sub-query if the sub-query returns NULL, use IFNULL(member_id, 0)

Comment: How to use this subquery @SPlatten?

Comment: Where you specify your tables, write "FROM (SELECT .....) t1, ct as t2"  The subquery is t1.  You could then use "joins" between t1 and t2 so that t2 is only used when t1 is valid.

Comment: I don't understand very well, sorry

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the time to write the query now, Google "mysql query join example"

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CROSS JOIN` to generate the rows and `LEFT JOIN` to bring in the data:

```
SELECT m.member_id, y.year,
       COALESCE(SUM(ct.amount_nitrogen), 0) as amount_nitrogen,   
       COALESCE(SUM(ct.amount_potassium), 0) as amount_potassium,
       COALESCE(SUM(ct.amount_phosphorus), 0) as amount_phosphorus,
       COALESCE(SUM(ct.amount_sodium_oxide), 0) as amount_sodium_oxide
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT member_id FROM ct) m CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT 2016 as year UNION ALL SELECT 2017 UNION ALL SELECT 2018
     ) y LEFT JOIN
     ct
     ON ct.member_id = m.member_id AND ct.year = y.year
GROUP BY m.member_id, y.year
```